# How do I add this to an array dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm storing div elements into an associative array, such that console will present such information to me. So console.log("enemyweakerpieces") gets me:

```
  Object {left: null, top: div#silver.drag, right: null, bot: div#gold.drag}
```

So far, so good.

Then I attempt to add this into an array or processing later on.

pullablepieces[0] = neighbors['top'];

This works fine. Console.log pullablepieces[0] gets me..

```
[div#silver.drag]
```

With a large tree of useful elements below. Good, good.

But if I try to do the same thing dynamically...

pullablepieces += neighbors['top'];

I get instead "DIV HTML OBJECT" and pullablepieces array gets 23 length for adding just one div object. I can't iterate through each one of them, its like the object gets spread out instead into the array I can't refer to it correctly.

How should I code it so that it'll preserve the integrity of the object, and still just store it into a single array element?

Comment: I'm not positive, but have you tried `pullablepieces[] = neighbors['top'];`?  Or even `pullablepieces[pullablepieces.length] = neighbors['top'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method:

`pullablepieces.push(neighbors['top']);`

Comment: I will try this. Most likely I was just being stupid and the += wrecked my code.

Answer (score 0):

If `pullablepieces` is an array, you add elements to the end of an array with `.push()`, not with `+=`.

```
pullablepieces.push(neighbors['top']);
```

---

In javascript, `+=` is a string or number operator so javascript will try to convert whatever you give it to one of those when you use that operator.  It is not an operator that works on an array.